# Split a bullet in 3 different directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, instantiation, rigid-bodies

I'm trying to assign a skill to a projectile that, when used, divides the project into 3 (the original projectile and 2 more new ones).

However, when I instantiate these two clones, I cannot attribute any movement to them. The idea would be for them to take [this route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi3Zv.png):

The green dotted curve indicating the motion of the original bullet, the blue vector indicating the instantaneous velocity of the original bullet at time of special activation, the red vectors indicating the two velocity vectors belonging to each of the newly spawned bullets, and the green angle indicating the direction of the new bullet relative to the original velocity direction

But at the moment, they are just standing at the point of the parabola where they were instantiated. No matter what I do, I can't seem to attach any value to their rigidbody2D. Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code so far

Ability Script:

```
public class AirSpecialSplit : MonoBehaviour, IAirSpecial
{
    public float SplitAngleInDegrees = 10;

    GameObject bird_down;
    GameObject bird_up;

    public void ExecuteAirSpecial()
    {
        {
            //hold the velocity of the original bird
            Vector2 original_velocity = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;

            //clone two new birds
            bird_down = Birb.MakeBirbCopy(this.gameObject);
            bird_up = Birb.MakeBirbCopy(this.gameObject);

            //get the rigidboy from the clones
            Rigidbody2D rb_bird_down = bird_down.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            Rigidbody2D rb_bird_up = bird_up.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            rb_bird_down.velocity = new Vector2(original_velocity.x, original_velocity.y) * Time.deltaTime;
            rb_bird_up.AddForce(new Vector2(3, 5) * 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Main Bird:

```
public class Birb : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Provided Code, Do Not Edit
    private Rigidbody2D m_rigidbody;

    private bool m_canExecuteAirSpecial = true;

    public bool CanExecuteAirSpecial
    {
        get
        {
            return m_rigidbody.simulated && m_canExecuteAirSpecial;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        m_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        StopBirbSimulation();
    }

    public void StopBirbSimulation()
    {
        m_rigidbody.simulated = false;
    }

    public void StartBirbSimulation()
    {
        m_rigidbody.simulated = true;
    }

    public void SetPosition( Vector3 position )
    {
        if ( m_rigidbody.simulated )
        {
            m_rigidbody.MovePosition( position );
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }

    public void ExecuteAirSpecial()
    {
        GetComponent<IAirSpecial>().ExecuteAirSpecial();
        m_canExecuteAirSpecial = false;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D( Collision2D collision )
    {
        m_canExecuteAirSpecial = false;
    }

    public static GameObject MakeBirbCopy( GameObject original )
    {
        Birb newBirb = Instantiate(original).GetComponent<Birb>();
        newBirb.m_canExecuteAirSpecial = false;
        return newBirb.gameObject;
    }
    #endregion

    [Range( 0, 25 )]
    public float LaunchForce = 12;

    public void Launch(Vector3 offset, float maximumStretch, Rigidbody2D rigidbody)
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(offset.x * -LaunchForce, offset.y * -LaunchForce) * (maximumStretch/2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently, I just need to set the "simulated" to true after instantiate.

```
    rb_bird_down.simulated = true;
    rb_bird_up.simulated = true;
```

The documentation could be clearer about this since they say that all attributes are copied, which is not the case...